# Will it be a safe to access elasticsearch directly from Javascript API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning elasticsearch. I wanted to know how safe (in terms of access control & validating user access) it is to access ES server directly from JavaScript API rather than accessing it through your backend ? Will it be a safe to access ES directly from Javascript API ?

Comment: Safe? Safe against what?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "safe".

If you mean "safe to expose to the internet", then no, definitely not, as there isn't any access control and anyone will be able to insert data or even drop all the indexes.

[This](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-in-production/) discussion gives a good overview of the issue.  Relevant section:

> Just as you would not expose a database directly to the Internet and let users send arbitrary SQL, you should not expose Elasticsearch to the world of untrusted users without sanitizing the input. Specifically, these are the problems we want to prevent:
>
> - Exposing private data. This entails limiting the searches to certain indexes, and/or applying filters to the searches.
> - Restricting who can update what.
> - Preventing expensive requests that can overwhelm or crash nodes and/or the entire cluster.
> - Preventing arbitrary code execution through dynamic scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Its most certainly possible, and it can be "safe" if say you're using it as an internal tool behind some kind of authentication. In general, no, its not secure. Elasticsearch API can create, delete, update, and search, which is not something you want to give a client access to or they could essentially do any or all of these things.

You could, in theory, create role based auth with ElasticSearch Shield, but it's far from standard practice. Its not really anymore difficult to implement search on your backend then just have a simple call to return search results.